# Want to run two instances of a mySql CRM app (one desk side and one webserver side) and want both databases to be synced

Tags: mysql, desktop, synchronization, dbase

Want to run two instances of a mySql CRM app (one desk side and one webserver side) and want both databases to be synced.

I like the CRM on the desktop because it is fast and I can set the settings as the admin for my viewing and I can continue working in the event of a loss of internet connectivity (then sync the dbase after reconnecting to the server dbase). I want to make a hosted instance of the CRM for my staff and when I am on the road. The databases should be showing the same data in real time. Effectively it is real time back-up system. Is there an existing way to already do this with mySql dbases without having to program anything? A plug-in or something?

Answer (score 0):

Try using MySQL replication http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

It is too long topic to start describing it here. Just search for information about implementing it.